# Using object in different module than original script

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

I just started with Python and I'm having some problems. I've written already a few scripts for ArcGIS and had some recurring stuff. So I thought it would be smart to put that in modules which I can easily use again.

So now I have two scripts, `script.py` and `toolbox.py`.
My script was working fine so I copied and paste the part I needed, edited it a bit and everything goes well except for the messages created with `gp.Addmessage`

script.py will create the message "Hello Stackoverflow" but the messages from toolbox.py doesn't show up. Why is that? It loads the toolbox because I can use it later on, so it regocnizes the gp object.

I'm kind of stuck here, would love to be able to print messages from inside the modules to inform the user of the tool what is happening.

`script.py`:

```
import os, sys, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

gp.AddMessage("# Hello Stackoverflow")

import toolbox
toolbox.loadToolbox
```

`toolbox.py`:

```
def loadToolbox:
    try:
      some code
      gp.AddToolbox(path)
      gp.AddMessage("# Toolbox loaded")
    except:
      gp.AddMessage("# Toolbox not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your code:

1. You never *call* the `loadToolBox` method, you only *refer* to it. Add `()`:

   ```
   toolbox.loadToolbox()
   ```
2. Your `loadToolbox()` function doesn't take `gp` as an argument. If `gp` is meant to be a global, then it won't be visible to the `toolbox` module (globals are only visible in the current module).

   Add `gp` as a parameter and pass it in when calling `loadToolbox`. In `script.py`:

   ```
   toolbox.loadToolbox(gp)
   ```

   and in `toolbox.py`:

   ```
   def loadToolbox(gp):
       # rest of function
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Got some other errors after that, one of them complaining about not finding os in toolbox.py but after passing that also as a parameter to the toolbox module it works like expected. So now I have 
toolbox.loadToolbox(gp, os)

def loadToolbox(gp):
    # rest of function

Comment: You should just add `import os` to your `toolbox` module then.